# Duplicate Record Error using lightning:recordEditForm

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm using `lightning:recordEditForm` on the `Account` object which also has duplicate rules set up. If I attempt to create a duplicate record via this form `lightning:messages` simply displays the following error:

> You're creating a duplicate record. We recommend you use an existing
>   record instead.

Whereas if I attempt to create a duplicate through the standard UI it provides a link which open a new modal showing the duplicate records and allowing the user to select one. Is there a straightforward way to replicate this or do I need to roll my own?

example code:

```
<aura:component>
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm" objectApiName="Contact">
    <lightning:messages />
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" />
    <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Create new" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience you have to build your own error handler and iterate through the results of the error message

So on the form, you add an onerror handler

```
<lightning:recordEditForm 
                          aura:id="recordEditForm" 
                          objectApiName="Contact"
                          onerror="{!c.handleError}"
                          >
```

And in the controller, you'd add something like this:

```
({
    handleError : function(component, event, helper) {

        component.set("v.showSpinner", false);
        var message = '';
        var errors = event.getParams();
        console.log(errors);
        var errormessages = errors.output;

        if ($A.util.isEmpty(errormessages.errors) === false) {
            if (errormessages.errors.length > 0) {
                for (var j = 0; errormessages.errors.length > j; j++) {
                    var fielderror = errormessages.errors[j];
                    if (fielderror.errorCode === 'DUPLICATES_DETECTED') {
                        message += 'Looks like this might be a duplicate. Click on the “Return to Search” button to find this contact';
                    }
                    else {
                        message += fielderror.errorCode + ' (' + fielderror.field + ') : ' + fielderror.message;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        toastEvent.setParams({
            "type": "error",
            "title": "Error on Save!",
            "message": message
        });
        toastEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

The error object will return something like this for Duplicate Matches, so you can iterate through the results and post something to the message and/or a toast

```
{
  "message": "An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again.",
  "detail": "Use one of these records?",
  "output": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "constituentField": null,
        "duplicateRecordError": {
          "matchResults": [
            {
              "apiName": "Contact",
              "isAllowSave": true,
              "matchRecordIds": [
                "003f400000gtfc2AAA"
              ],
              "matchRule": "Standard_Contact_Match_Rule_v1_1",
              "objectLabel": "Contact",
              "objectLabelPlural": "Contacts",
              "themeInfo": {
                "color": "A094ED",
                "iconUrl": "https://lexpictures-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/img/icon/t4v35/standard/contact_120.png"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "errorCode": "DUPLICATES_DETECTED",
        "field": null,
        "fieldLabel": null,
        "message": "Use one of these records?"
      }
    ],
    "fieldErrors": {

    }
  },
  "error": {

  }
}
```

Comment: This is what we do. The problem is that even the non-blocking duplicate rules are still blocking the save.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will have to roll something on your own leveraging [DuplicateResult Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Datacloud_DuplicateResult.htm). Below is an example of vfpage that shows a custom application that lets users add a contact. When a contact is saved, an alert displays if there are duplicate records.

**Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="ContactDedupeController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Duplicate Records" rendered="{!hasDuplicateResult}">
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!duplicateRecords}" var="item">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLink value="/{!item['Id']}">{!item['Name']}</apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Owner</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!item['OwnerId']}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Last Modified Date</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!item['LastModifiedDate']}"/>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable> 
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock title="Contact" mode="edit">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>         

            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.FirstName}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.LastName}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Email}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Phone}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.AccountId}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class ContactDedupeController {

    // Initialize a variable to hold the contact record you're processing
    private final Contact contact;

    // Initialize a list to hold any duplicate records
    private List<sObject> duplicateRecords;

    // Define variable that’s true if there are duplicate records
    public boolean hasDuplicateResult{get;set;}

    // Define the constructor
    public ContactDedupeController() {

        // Define the values for the contact you’re processing based on its ID
        Id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        this.contact = (id == null) ? new Contact() : 
            [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone, AccountId 
             FROM Contact WHERE Id = :id];

        // Initialize empty list of potential duplicate records
        this.duplicateRecords = new List<sObject>();
        this.hasDuplicateResult = false;
    }

    // Return contact and its values to the Visualforce page for display
    public Contact getContact() {
        return this.contact;
    }

    // Return duplicate records to the Visualforce page for display
    public List<sObject> getDuplicateRecords() {
        return this.duplicateRecords;
    }

    // Process the saved record and handle any duplicates
    public PageReference save() {

        // Optionally, set DML options here, use “DML” instead of “false” 
        //   in the insert()
        // Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions(); 
        // dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.allowSave = true;
        // dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.runAsCurrentUser = true;
        Database.SaveResult saveResult = Database.insert(contact, false);

        if (!saveResult.isSuccess()) {
            for (Database.Error error : saveResult.getErrors()) {
                // If there are duplicates, an error occurs
                // Process only duplicates and not other errors 
                //   (e.g., validation errors)
                if (error instanceof Database.DuplicateError) {
                    // Handle the duplicate error by first casting it as a 
                    //   DuplicateError class
                    // This lets you use methods of that class 
                    //  (e.g., getDuplicateResult())
                    Database.DuplicateError duplicateError = 
                            (Database.DuplicateError)error;
                    Datacloud.DuplicateResult duplicateResult = 
                            duplicateError.getDuplicateResult();

                    // Display duplicate error message as defined in the duplicate rule
                    ApexPages.Message errorMessage = new ApexPages.Message(
                            ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Duplicate Error: ' + 
                            duplicateResult.getErrorMessage());
                    ApexPages.addMessage(errorMessage);

                    // Get duplicate records
                    this.duplicateRecords = new List<sObject>();

                    // Return only match results of matching rules that 
                    //  find duplicate records
                    Datacloud.MatchResult[] matchResults = 
                            duplicateResult.getMatchResults();

                    // Just grab first match result (which contains the 
                    //   duplicate record found and other match info)
                    Datacloud.MatchResult matchResult = matchResults[0];

                    Datacloud.MatchRecord[] matchRecords = matchResult.getMatchRecords();

                    // Add matched record to the duplicate records variable
                    for (Datacloud.MatchRecord matchRecord : matchRecords) {
                        System.debug('MatchRecord: ' + matchRecord.getRecord());
                        this.duplicateRecords.add(matchRecord.getRecord());
                    }
                    this.hasDuplicateResult = !this.duplicateRecords.isEmpty();
                }
            }

            //If there’s a duplicate record, stay on the page
            return null;
        }

        //  After save, navigate to the view page:
        return (new ApexPages.StandardController(contact)).view();
    }

}
```

You need to do something like the above example to look for the duplicates in the onError or onSubmit in your lightning component and display the relevant details.