# lightning:recordEditForm with duplicates and allow save option

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

Im using lightning:recordEditForm with a simple save button as follows:

```
<lightning:button aura:id="saveEdit" label="Save" class="slds-button_brand" type="submit"/>
```

I also have a duplicate rule on the object, which has the option of allowing the user to ignore and still save the record if it finds a duplicate. However as this is an Apex-less method of saving i cant set the allowSave option e.g.

```
    Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions();
    dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.allowSave = true;
```

so i just hit a hard stop everytime, how can i add in Save & Ignore style functionality that the user would see on a standard new record page?

Comment: Duplicate question - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/238047/duplicate-record-error-using-lightningrecordeditform

Comment: that doesn't explain how to "Save and Ignore" only how to access the potential duplicate records for display

Comment: not quite sure I follow - when you say ' how can i add in Save & Ignore ' what exactly are you expecting as an answer? for someone to help you figure out how to add a 2nd Save button where you can call a form submit which will then call an apex method you have?

Comment: He wants to know how to set dml options with lightning record edit form. I am looking for a solution to this as well, but I, too, think you have to roll your own save function.

Comment: This was also asked here, but with no answer: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279252/duplicate-rule-bypass-with-recordeditform-in-lightning

I am guessing it's just not within the functionality of recordEditForm. There's no mention of anything like this in the docs, it's just frustrating because it's all core functionality that doesn't actually work together!