# Duplicate Rule Bypass with RecordEditForm in Lightning

Tags: apex, lightning, controller, lightning-recordeditform

I am struggling with figuring out how to pass

> dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.allowSave = true;

in Apex on a Lightning RecordEditForm component. I am using RecordEditForm as a record creation form and unsure how alter the payload.

I am assuming I would pass something off from the lightning controller "onSubmit"  to an apex controller.

Appreciate the help in advance.